# Reduce the size of Google app engine Datastore Stored Data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google app engine and now the size of the "Datastore Stored Data" is near to exceed the free quota limit. so i want to reduce the size of the data in the Datastore by removing some entity elements.

I have tried deleting some entity elements that cost about 100MB (abt 10% from 1GB limit) , but it still shows the earlier usage and it still near to exceed the free quota limit.

Please advice me, how to reduce the data store size.

Thanks in advance.

Nalaka

Comment: From the admin console : Statistics are updated at least once per day.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the size in your case:

1) NDB can compress properties, so you can create an object for the non indexed properties and compress it: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties?hl=nl

2) I do not know your models. But an option is to distribute your models and create a webservice to fetch entities from the other appids.

3) If it is only one model, you keep the indexed properties in your primary appid and fetch the data from the secondary appid.

But of course, everything has a price. Performance, url fetches, CPU ... So it is easy to run from one bottleneck in another.